# Asp.Net MVC - Mixed Auth Mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for the most reliable way to use both Windows and Form based auth *IN ASP.NET MVC 2* I know how to do it in webforms, but because I cannot adjust the permissions (In IIS) on a per file basis in MVC. Im struggling to transfer the concept.

Any suggestions? Links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are following post:
http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/03/10/2562.aspx
http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/03/10/2561.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

All describe it for classic asp.net. But the concept should be transferable to mvc. 
I implemented this using mvc and a custom membership provider.

The whole application is running with aspnet anonymous account. That means that your files must be accessible to this account. On my machine I had to give read access to this IIS account.