# Windows authentication using C# code in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

I am trying to have both windows as well as forms authentication for my application. For Forms Authentication I wrote my custom membership provider to handle authentication. I want to do the same for windows authentication also.

**Can we control windows authentication using code?** 
Thanks

Comment: use search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873327/asp-net-mvc-mixed-auth-mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629194/asp-net-mvc-multipleforms-and-windows-authorization-models

Comment: @VladimirShmidt: I think u did not understand the question and copy pasted something irrelevant.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126098/session-management-with-asp-net-mvc-iis-6-0-basic-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key is to lock in on the username for intranet users, but redirect other users to a custom logon screen for username and password.

Here are two articles that discuss mixing forms and windows security in ASP.NET.

1. [Mixing Forms and Windows Security in ASP.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx)
2. [Windows Authentication with Forms Fallback](http://blog.toolroom.at/post/MVC-Windows-authentication-with-forms-fallback.aspx)